# FrameLayout and setLayoutParams invalides my View

Tags: java, android, graphics, canvas

I have a strange behaviour with a implementation of Canvas I am having.

I am doing simple Canvas, draw something on it and all that's fine. But then, I put Button over that View (in a FrameLayout), like this:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);
button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

When 'setLayoutParams' is called, the whole View gets redrawn/invalidated. I don't understand why, but then I have problems because of this.
It's not a problem to be called the first time, but the View is invalidated all the time when the 'setLayoutParams' is called. This causes some trouble later on.

Maybe someone would suggest me some idea on how to avoid this?

Comment: Visual changes such as setLayoutParams should invalidate the view hierarchy. Tell us what you know about your particular hierarchy that leads you expect that an invalidate shouldn't (or needn't) happen.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to move the button, you should change your code to this:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If your trying to move the frame layout, change it to this:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams)frameLayout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```